# How can I use categories to filter entries?

Tags: templating, entries, categories

It's a pretty basic question, but for some reason all of the possible solutions do not work for me.

I tried this: https://craftcms.com/docs/relations#the-relatedTo-param
And also this (which I really expected to solve my problem): https://craftcms.com/support/entries-related-to-category

I'm pretty sure I may have overlooked something, but I can't see what.

I made this:

```
{% set lastSeg = craft.request.lastSegment %}
{% set meubels = craft.entries.section('meubels').relatedTo(lastSeg) %}
```

And use this as a test:

```
{% for meub in meubels %}
test<br>
{{ meub.title }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

According to every answer to related questions this should work, but unfortunately it returns nothing. But `lastSegment` does return the required string from the URL. (At least, I'm assuming this must be a string)

I made a list of categories which all seem to route just fine, no problems there.

Comment: Are you trying to do this from a url that is a category route?

Comment: Yes, I try to get the last segment from the url and the url is analysed through a category route with a wildcard.

Comment: If the URL is routed form your category, you have access to a variable `category` in your template. `category` is the category model for whatever category you were routed to, so you might be able to skip the first step in my answer!

Comment: Ah, indeed, you're right. This saves some lines of code. Thanks once more! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `relatedTo` parameter requires one of the following as an argument:
- AssetFileModel
- CategoryModel
- EntryModel
- UserModel
- TagModel
- An element’s ID
- An array of element objects and/or IDs

Passing in a string from the URL will not work. If you are not on a template that is the result of a category route, you need to fetch the category first.

```
{% set thisCategory = craft.categories.handle(lastSeg).first() %}
```

You can then use `thisCategory` as your argument in the `relatedTo` parameter.

```
{% set meubels = craft.entries.section(‘meubels’).relatedTo(thisCategory) %}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was not aware of the required first line.

Comment: Although it first did not work as expected (it returned all entries that had any category connected to it). I changed `{% set thisCategory = craft.categories.handle(lastSeg).first() %}` to `{% set thisCategory = craft.categories.title(lastSeg) %}` and now it works! :)